# How to automatically refresh access token with interceptor + route guard?

Tags: angular, jwt

I've browsed a ton of articles & questions but none seem to cover automatic token refresh in an interceptor WHILE also having a route guard that waits for a request to* the server to complete to verify that the access token is valid?

**auth.guard.ts**

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .pipe(
        map(
          res => {
            if (res.success === true) {
              return true;
            } else {
              this.authService.deleteToken();
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
              return false;
            }
          }
        ), catchError(err => {
          // NOTE: If I put the code for refresh-token request here, it works -- user stays
          // logged in after getting new access token

          this.authService.deleteToken();
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return of(false);
        })
      );
  }
```

**auth.interceptor.ts**

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.headers.get('noauth')) {
      return next.handle(req.clone());
    } else {
      const clonedReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getToken())
      });

      return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
        tap(
          event => {},
          err => {
            if (err.error.code && err.error.code === 'EXPIRED') {
                return this.handle401Error(clonedReq, next);
            }
          }
        )
      );
    }
  }

  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
        switchMap((token: any) => {
          this.isRefreshing = false;
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.new_access_token);
          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.new_access_token));
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          return throwError(err);
        }))
        .subscribe(r => r);

    } else {
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(token => token != null),
        take(1),
        switchMap(jwt => {
          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, jwt));
        }));
    }
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
refreshToken() {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.api}/refresh-token`, {
      'refreshToken': this.getRefreshToken()
    }, this.noAuthHeader).pipe(tap((res) => {
      if (res.success === true) {
        this.setToken(res.new_access_token);
        return true;
      } else {
        this.deleteToken();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        return false;
      }
    }));
  }
```

---

What happens is:

1. User tries to access a secured route
2. **auth.guard.ts** sends request to server to verify access token validity
3. Access token has expired, so the server responds with 401
4. The request for refreshing the token gets sent, but the initial request for simply validating the access token gets completed first -- the user gets redirected to login page, instead of staying logged in
5. The request for refresh token completes

I'm not sure how it's supposed to happen but what I'm thinking is that the request for getting a new access token should get completed first, and then the authentication request/auth.guard should base on that?

Comment: when you have handled deleting old token and navigating to the login page in your `refreshToken()` method why you have totally `catchError` in your `isAuthenticated()` again?

Comment: Hi @roya, if I understood you correctly, are you suggesting that I don't need the `catchError` in the `auth.guard`? I actually just tried that, but I get an error: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse:...` including the response from the server saying the access token has expired. Sequence: 1)  Send `/user/auth` -> verify access token 2) 401 response, send `/refresh-token` 3) ERROR (above) 4) `/refresh-token` responds with new token 5) `/user/auth` is resent with new token -> succeeds 6) Nothing happens, user can't proceed to secure route

Comment: can you prepare a plunker or something like that? otherwise this article may help you [link](https://medium.com/@satyapriyamishra111/angular-error-interceptor-4b102f938065)

Comment: @roya I'll check out that link and try to reproduce my issue on stackblitz, thank you!

Comment: Hi @roya here's the stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hhs9jd?file=src/app/auth/auth.guard.ts

Comment: i looked that and changed some parts in interceptor file. check out the result [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ranpb6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth%2Fauth.interceptor.ts) also i see a bunch of unnecessary parts like subject behavior, what do u want to do exactly? i could not read all of your code today. also u can write it cleaner usin `retryWhen` please read it.

Comment: @roya I was following a tutorial https://angular-academy.com/angular-jwt/, and the `BehaviorSubject` is in case there are multiple requests while the new access token is being fetched.

Comment: i red the link and still think you can write it better. by the way did you test the changes i made to your stackblitz?
even if you are doing as the tutorial said you had some mistakes in it and your code wasn't exactly what the tutorial said! pls read it carefully...

Comment: @roya I can't follow the code in the tutorial exactly because we have different requirements, like how in his `auth.guard` he didn't need to send a request to verify the user, he just checks locally. Anyway, I think I fixed the error on my own, I'll post the answer in a bit. I also did check out the link you sent, but it's still throwing up the same error on my end, I don't know if you just sent me the wrong link. But thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After being stuck for a day and a half, I think I finally fixed it on my own:

**auth.guard.ts**

```
return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .pipe(
        map(
          res => {
            if (res.success === true) {
              return true;
            } else {
              this.authService.deleteToken();
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
              return false;
            }
          }
        ), catchError(
          err => {

            // Absolutely needed this handler, 
            // but removed the code for redirection to login and deletion of tokens
            return of(false);
          }
        )
      );
```

**auth.interceptor.ts**

```
return next.handle(clonedReq)
        .pipe(
          catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.error.code === 'EXPIRED') {
                  return this.handle401Error(clonedReq, next);
            } else if (err.error.status === 401) {
                  this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
                  return throwError(err.error.message);
            }

            // Redirect to an error landing page
            return throwError(err.error.message);
          })
        );

private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      return this.authService.refreshToken()
        .pipe(
          switchMap((token: any) => {
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.new_access_token);
          this.authService.setToken(token.new_access_token);

          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.new_access_token));
        }), catchError(err => { 

          // .subscribe() not needed!Just an error handler
          if (err.error.code === 'EXPIRED') {
                this.authService.deleteToken();
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
                return throwError(err.error.message);
          }
          
          // Redirect to error landing page
          return throwError(err.error.message);
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        this.isRefreshing = false;
      })
    );
...
```

I hope you find this helpful!